# Generating a C# partial class with SWIG

Tags: c#, swig

I am trying generate a partial C# class following [the example given in the SWIG documentation](https://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/CSharp.html#csharp_partial_classes), but the generated C# class is not partial.

My files:

**ExtendMe.h**

```
class ExtendMe {
public:
  int Part1() { return 1; }
};
```

**Extend.i**

```
%module Extend

%include "ExtendMe.h"
%typemap(csclassmodifiers) ExtendMe "public partial class"
```

I run `swig -csharp -c++ Extend.i`, and the generated ExtendMe.cs contains `public class ExtendMe` rather than `public partial class ExtendMe`

Comment: There's no such thing as a C# "partial class". The `partial` keyword in a class definition indicates that the full class definition is spread out over multiple C# source files in the same compilation. Are you just trying to have your tool generate some code that has the `partial` keyword, or are you trying to do something more esoteric

Comment: @Flydog57 I just want the `partial` keyword in the generated code, so I can define more members in another file.

Comment: It turns out it was as simple as putting the %typemap before the %include

Comment: You should add an answer (a self answer) to your question so that it can be found later by someone with the same problem you had. Ping me with an @ reference on the question and I'll upvote you (to make it more visible to a search). Remember, the point of this site is to build a library of answers